# No me suma string al usar el operador += en php

Tags: php

Buen día mi problema es que al intentar sumar lo que tengo en una variable con el operador += no me realiza la suma. Al hacer un var_dump($valor) muestra esto

```
string(4) "1000" string(4) "1000" string(3) "500"
```

Lo que quiero es que me sume cada string y me lo guarde en una variable, así que, aplique esto:

```
$valor2 = 0;
$valor2 += $valor;
```

Pero en vez de que $valor2 me valga 2500 que es lo que necesito, al hacer un var_dump($valor2) me devuelve esto:

```
int(1000) int(1000) int(500)
```

Osea que me da los valores por separado y al mostrarlo con un echo""; solo me muestra el último valor que es 500, lo que quiero es que me muestre 2500 que es la suma de todos los valores, de ante mano muchísimas gracias.

Comment: var_dump es para imprimir arrays, mejor prueba con un simple echo.

Comment: Valor es un array?

Comment: "Esta función muestra información estructurada sobre una o más expresiones incluyendo su tipo y valor. Las matrices y los objetos son explorados recursivamente con valores sangrados para mostrar su estructura.

En PHP 5 todas las propiedades públicas, privadas y protegidas de los objetos serán devueltas en la salida." 

Probaste con echo?

Comment: Hola amigos no valor no es un array, es un string y con echo solo muestra el último valor es decir 500

Comment: Y si hago un echo $valor dentro del foreach que lo tengo me lo muestra asi 10001000500

Comment: Un array debes recorrerlo, te aconsejo que busques el apartado de arrays para que estés más claro, los vectores, arrays, listas y objetos pueden generar confusión al inicio.

Comment: Está bien gracias hermano

Comment: más que proponerte una solución, te recomendaría que estudiaras los tipos de datos en PHP y cómo manejar y sumar ints y strings. saludos!

Comment: Gracias amigo me estoy en eso.

Answer (score 2):

El modo mas simple sería:

- Usar `array_sum` para sumar los valores de cada posición del vector
- Declarar una variable que almacene dicha suma
- Imprimir la variable que esta almacenando la suma
- De la forma anterior tu no necesitarías alguna iteración de forma explícita para recorrer y sumar los elementos:

Así:

```
$valor = array("100", "200", "500");

$suma = array_sum($valor);

echo $suma;
```

Dando:

> 800

Ahora que si deseas utilizar dicha sintaxis, entonces podría hacer lo siguiente:

- Declara una variable que almacenará el total de la suma igualada a 0
- Itera con un ciclo foreach al vector
- Dentro del ciclo le igualas y sumas el valor de cada posición iterada
- Imprimes el valor por fuera:

Así:

```
$valor = array("100", "200", "500");

$total = 0;

foreach($valor as $numero)
{
    $total += $numero;
}

echo $total;
```

Dando de nuevo:

> 800